# Querying and updating votes with Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to set up a voting system Parse as my backend.

I want to use swipe left and right as the voting method and I am using a `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithID` so that I can update the vote count to my backend.

I am having trouble querying it and also saving the votes in the back and having that append in to the cell so that the vote count will be added on the tableview cells.

Keep on receiving this error in my log for the query:

> no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.2)

How can I correct this? Also How can I make the voting system work after I get the query to work and update the backend?

Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class HomePage: UITableViewController {

    let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var titles = [String]()
    var imageFile = [PFFile]()
     var voteCounter = 0

    var count = [Int]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.limit = 15
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil  {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                println(objects!)
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                        if let title = object["Title"] as? String {
                            self.titles.append(title)
                        }
                        if let imgFile = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                            self.imageFile.append(imgFile)
                        }
                        if let voteCounter = object["count"] as? Int {
                        self.count.append(voteCounter)
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println(error)
            }
        }

    }
            }




                /* println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

                for object in objects! {

                    self.titles.append(object["Title"] as! String)

                    self.imageFile.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }*/



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return titles.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 500

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell

        myCell.rank.text = "21"
        myCell.votes.text = "\(count)"
        myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

            }
        }

        var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

This is the query that I get errors on:

```
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("count") {
    (Post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
    println(error)
    } else if let Post = Post {
    Post["count"] = self.voteCounter
    Post.saveInBackground()
    }
    }

        return myCell

    }

    func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                voteCounter += 1
                println("Swiped right")
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                voteCounter -= 1
                println("Swiped Left")
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Also here is my Parse backend:

[image: Parse]

ive added the new code now

```
     import UIKit
import Parse


class HomePage: UITableViewController {

    let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var titles = [String]()
    var imageFile = [PFFile]()
    var votingObjects: [PFObject] = []

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.limit = 15
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil  {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                println(objects!)
                for objectRaw in objects! {
                    let object = objectRaw as! PFObject

                    self.votingObjects.append(object)
                    // Adding them to the array
                    if let title = object["Title"] as? String {
                        self.titles.append(title)
                    }
                    if let imgFile = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.imageFile.append(imgFile)
                    }


                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData() 
// Updating the tableView on the main thread - important. Do some research on Grand Central Dispatch :)
                })
            } else {
                println(error)
                // Error
            }
        }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return titles.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 500

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell

        myCell.rank.text = "21"
```

i cant figure out whats the right code here for the myCell.votes.text to =

```
        myCell.votes.text = votingObjects[indexPath.row]["count"] as? String
        myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

            }
        }

        var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        return myCell

    }
```

having an issue here:

```
        func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                updateVote(true, objectId: String())
                println("Swiped right")
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                updateVote(false, objectId: String())
                println("Swiped Left")
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    func updateVote(increment: Bool, objectId : String) {

        // Create a pointer to an object of class Posts with id 'objectId'
        var object = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Post", objectId: objectId)

        // Increment the current value of the quantity key by 1
        if increment == true {
            object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: 1)
        } else {
            object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
        }

        // Save
        object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
    }
}
```

but i keep recieving the error of cannot update without specific objectId whenever i swipe and initiate the gesture recognizer. i also cant figure out how to display the votes in my cell

Comment: It is good practice to keep your class names starting with a capital and your column/field names starting with a lowercase letter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are querying the Parse db for an objectID which doesn't exist. This is because when you receive the objects, the attribute "count" is the number of votes right... but when you query for an object, you are using "count" as the objectID which obviously won't work. Your idea of using the variable count will also not work.

What I would recommend is a slight adjustment in your structures.

When receiving the objects from the initial query, store them in an array of Parse Objects. This way, you retain all of their information and it will be much easier to update them. The will also provide an attribute object.objectId which is a String, which is what you will need when querying the db again.

Another tip is Parse supports an increment function when dealing with a column of type `number`

Also, when working on background threads, you should make any UI calls on the main thread using GCD.

Code:

Initial query -

```
var votingObjects: [PFObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.limit = 15
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil  {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                println(objects!)
                for objectRaw in objects {
                    let object = objectRaw as! PFObject
                    self.votingObjects.append(object) // Adding them to the array
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData() // Updating the tableView on the main thread - important. Do some research on Grand Central Dispatch :)
                })
            } else {
                // Error
            }
        }
    }
    // Pass true if you want to upvote or false if downvote
    func updateVote(increment: Bool, objectId : String) {
        // Create a pointer to an object of class Posts with id 'objectId'
        var object = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Posts", objectId: objectId)

        // Increment the current value of the quantity key by 1
        if increment == true {
            object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: 1)
        } else {
            object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
        }

        // Save
        object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
    }
}
```

Your tableView functions will all link to the array now..

numberOfRows will simply use `votingObjects.count`
TitleForRow will use `votingObject[indexPath.row]["Title"]! // Should be 'title'`

And any time you want to refer to a voting objects ID, you simply use `votingObject[index].objectId`

Hope I didn't miss anything :)

Comment: how can i store them in an array of Parse Objects? also how can i then query all the objectIDs so i can get the other objects in them?

Comment: Notice at the top I've created the array `votingObjects`... Thats the array they are all stored in.

Comment: I think you are missing some fundamental understanding about parse objects. Each object in that array will contain everything you need - no more querying after that.

Comment: i cant tell you how much i appreciate this! and yea im pretty new to this i will definitely be doing a lot more research and this was extremely helpful

Comment: Im glad to hear that :) Enjoy!

Comment: thanks a lot for the help but im running in to some trouble with the objectId i keep recieving error message of cannot update without specific objectId i added an edit of what i currently have now.